# Intellij idea module dependency

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Problem description for short: in a project has multiple modules, one of them import classes from other modules. Now when I run unit test in this module, the compilation fails because they can not find imported classes. However in project structure, the module dependencies are in the dependency list (blue circled in the following picture). How to solve this cannot find classes from other modules problem in intellij idea?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Something very similar happened me when I was using IntelliJ with Gradle as my dependency management tool. 
I found that going by IntelliJ's view of dependencies alone, was not enough. Be sure to explicitly include those dependencies in your pom.xml also.

e.g.
Module 'main-app' has a dependency on Module 'main-db' in my project.

Using Gradle, a simple addition of:

```
compile project(':main-db')
```

to 'main-app''s build.gradle file would fix these issue you're having.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: The three dependencies have already been in pom.xml, while just cannot directly run unit test without first running mvn install. :(

Comment: I see, I have the Gradle plugin for IntelliJ set to 'Auto Update'. So any changes made do not require a clean install. @Tiina

Answer (score 2):

After import the module, sometimes you need to find the src directory and go to Mark Directory as -> "Sources Root".

Answer (score 0):

Check that your class files in your dependencies are in a folder that is marked as a 'src' folder. Otherwise IntelliJ dont know, that the files there a class files.
[image]